# Extract values from data table

Tags: r, datatable

I have the following data table (in the example I just take 3 rows):

```
data <- data.table(var=c("a","b","c"), value=c(-1,2,1))
```

I would like to extract each variable as value without subsetting each time that I need one of them.
I would like to get the follwing output:

```
a <- -1
b <- 2
c <- 1
```

Comment: You really shouldn't do that. Be glad that you have these values nicely together in one data structure.

Answer (score 2):

An option is `split` to return a `key/value` pair.  It is better not to create objects in the global environment

```
lst1 <- split(data$value, data$var)
lst1
#$a
#[1] -1

#$b
#[1] 2

#$c
#[1] 1
```

But, if we need it,

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
a
#[1] -1
b
#[1] 2
c
#[1] 1
```

---

Or another option is `deframe` and then use `list2env`

```
library(tibble)
list2env(as.list(deframe(data)), .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though creating objects in the global environment is not recommended, we can try `eval(parse(...))` methodology to address your question,

```
eval(parse(text = do.call(paste, c(data, sep = '<-'))))
a
#[1] -1
b
#[1] 2
c
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`:

```
 res<-purrr::map2(data$var, data$value, 
            function(x,y) 
             x <- y

            )
names(res) <- data$var
```

The above sets the names after getting the result.

```
res

$a
[1] -1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 1
```

With `base`'s `mapply`, we could use:

```
  as.list(mapply(function(x,y) assign(x,y,new.env()),
       data$var,data$value))
$a
[1] -1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 1
```

Or:

```
 mapply(function(x,y) append(list(),y),
       data$var,data$value)
$a
[1] -1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 1
```